# Using crypto module in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, security, cryptography

I have the following scenario:

*Client and server are connected by using node.js .
Client needs to send password to server, so I want to encrypt it.
Without talking about the security protocol I want to use, I need some library to make my life easier. I read there are several kind of them (crypto for example).*

The problem is that, If client side needs to download these libraries from server side and the connections is 'in clear' , may this security protocol be reliable?

I hope the question is clear.

EDIT: I need to add some details:

I'd like to use a symmetric encryption:
First Client and server exchange password using Diffie-Hellman (For the moment no problem about 'man in the middle attack')
Then using that key (and a cipher, for example AES) client can send password to server.

To make that, I need some libraries to make my life easier.

Comment: https has encryption. You should not need another one if you are using it. Always use it.

Comment: Are you simply confused about how password authentication generally works? The password is never encrypted on the clientside, except for with SSL, it's sent in plain text, but it's never stored on the server either, a hash is stored on the server and compared against the sent password, or are you devising some sort of custom approach that for some strange reason requires clientside encryption. I'm thinking the answer to your question is that you don't need to encrypt passwords on the clientside, it's all done serverside.

Comment: @adeneo Client should send his password, in which sense is it never encrypted on the clientSide?

Comment: Well, what sort of authentication is this, just regular login? As far as I know no websites today encrypt the password clientside. With SSL everything is encrypted to protect against attacks when the data is between user and server, but there's no encryption on the clientside of passwords. Passwords are sent in plain text to the server, and on the server they are compared agains a salted hash and then discarded, this is how just about every login system works

Comment: @user568109 at the moment I am not using https

Comment: @adeneo You are telling me: "Password are sent in clear at application level, then they are crypted in SSL level?", aren't you?

Comment: Encryption done in connection basis is much stronger/efficient than only particular part of data. What adeneo is saying is that use of SSL in transport layer does not need to be done by client/user. It is implicitly done.

Comment: Passwords are always sent as plain text, yes. Even if you don't use SSL, passwords are sent in plain text, as the only security risk is generally "man in the middle" or someone actually seeing what the user types on the keyboard, there's a much higher risk of an attack on the server, so you never store the password on the server, and that is generally enough. If your application stores sensitive personal data you should always use SSL as well, but for just your average username/password login it's not really needed.

Comment: Now you've added Diffie-Hellmann to the question, and that's an interesting approach as it uses keys sent to the client etc. and it is supported by Node, but Diffie-Hellmann is generally very hard to do right, and in most cases it's not used as it's complexity makes it hard to handle.

Comment: Using libraries I think I can use Diffie-Hellmann protocol, why are you talking about hard task?

Comment: If you think Diffie-Hellmann is easy to use, by all means go ahead.

Comment: Just use HTTPS. Then the connection is not just encrypted without any further programmatically effort but the client has also a way to verify that the server is the one it’s pretending to be.

Comment: @adeneo TLS or SSL is needed for username + password. It's not always used, but that's actually pretty bad. Especially in cases where the IP routing cannot be controlled (any open WiFi access point or GSM transmission) HTTPS is an absolute must. TLS is cheap, use it. And you cannot have JavaScript security measures without it as an attacker may change the JavaScript code itself.

Comment: @owlstead - so basically what you're saying is that the billions of forums, or websites that just require a email and password to post a comment, is doing it wrong and should be using SSL? How much security you need should be based on what data you require, if you just need a random username and password to login, you don't need SSL, as there's no personal information, credit card numbers etc. to protect.

Comment: @adeneo Yes, that's what I am saying. Of course security depends on the type of information. But with the high amount of password re-use, you may not want to leak the password. If possible, at least protect the login. There are many fake hotspots out there, beware.